# What can cause a slope different than one in the fitted vs observed plot of a linear mixed model?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I have ran a quite simple linear mixed model with lmer from r:

lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|id), data = df)

The data I used contains about 9000 measures of y for 3000 subjects, measured at three different conditions. When I was looking at the residuals plot I noticed a slope, and when I checked the fitted vs observed it just seems that the model didn't adjust properly.

Any ideas on what might be going on? What can be causing this odd slope?

Would a similar model with the grouping variable as fixed effect, if giving the same slope, be valid for inferential statistics (to test differences between groups)?

[image]

Comment: maybe (??) heteroscedasticity among groups (i.e. variation in within-group variance among groups) ??

Comment: with within-group variance do you mean different variances between the three different conditions? Even if they are not modelled directly in the model? Do you think lme from nlme library would be more appropriate because it allows to model heteroscedasticity?